# Java ICAP File Transfer Problem, File Is Corrupted

Tags: java, jboss, network-programming, netty, icap

I am working with an ICAP github project located [here](https://github.com/jmimo/netty-icap) which is based off JBoss Netty codecs.  My current problem which likely stems from my inability to properly understand netty handlers and Httpchunks along with lack of programming skills is I do not know how to write the data returned to a file successfully.  Basically my code so far is able to push content to a file but the file is always corrupt whether it is I am missing data, not performing it correctly, or am putting it together wrong I am not entirely sure.  The code is below.  Any suggestions or assistance I would love.  Thanks in advance.

```
package ch.mimo.netty.example.icap.preview;

import org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.MessageEvent;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler;

import ch.mimo.netty.handler.codec.icap.DefaultIcapResponse;
import ch.mimo.netty.handler.codec.icap.IcapChunk;
import ch.mimo.netty.handler.codec.icap.IcapChunkTrailer;
import ch.mimo.netty.handler.codec.icap.IcapRequest;
import ch.mimo.netty.handler.codec.icap.IcapResponse;
import ch.mimo.netty.handler.codec.icap.IcapResponseStatus;
import ch.mimo.netty.handler.codec.icap.IcapVersion;

public class IcapServerHandler extends SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler {

    private boolean continueWasSent;

    @Override
    public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent e) throws Exception {
        Object msg = e.getMessage();
        if(msg instanceof IcapRequest) {
            IcapRequest request = (IcapRequest)e.getMessage();
            System.out.println(request.toString());
        } else if(msg instanceof IcapChunkTrailer) {
            System.out.println(msg.toString());
            if(!continueWasSent) {
                continueWasSent = true;
                // sending 100 continue in order to receive the rest of the message
                IcapResponse response = new DefaultIcapResponse(IcapVersion.ICAP_1_0,IcapResponseStatus.CONTINUE);
                ctx.getChannel().write(response);
            } else {
                // sending 204 No Content response
                IcapResponse response = new DefaultIcapResponse(IcapVersion.ICAP_1_0,IcapResponseStatus.NO_CONTENT);
                ctx.getChannel().write(response);
            }
        } else if(msg instanceof IcapChunk) {
            IcapChunk request3 = (IcapChunk)e.getMessage();
           System.out.println(request3.getContent().toString(Charset.defaultCharset()));
            testfile = "C:\\Users\\dan\\Desktop\\iso\\netty\\" + output;
            buffer = request3.getContent();
            ByteBuffer nioBuffer = buffer.toByteBuffer();
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(testfile);
            FileChannel channel = fos.getChannel();
            while (nioBuffer.hasRemaining()) {
                channel.write(nioBuffer);
            }
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
            System.out.println(msg);
        } 
    }

}
```

Also, I should say for small text files I am able to successfully rebuild the file locally.  However, say with larger .docx files when I try to build the file I am not getting the full size and the file is corrupt.  At this point I really am not sure what to try next.

Comment: Your issue is caused by the fact that 1 file may exists out of multiple `IcapChunk`'s, but I'm not experienced with the Icap protocol to give you instructions to to merge those packets together, but the following handler might help you: https://github.com/jmimo/netty-icap/blob/master/src/main/java/ch/mimo/netty/handler/codec/icap/IcapChunkAggregator.java

Comment: Thanks for your advise.  Not sure why but once I changed the conversion from file to bytes using the below code it worked for me.  file2bytestream = Files.readAllBytes(testfilePath);